# Unable to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: upgrade

I have a working Ubuntu 18.04 installation, and trying to upgrade to 18.10 (as I have successfully done on several of my other systems). However, on this system, "do-release-upgrade" fails without an error message. Here is the output:

```
# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,263 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,264 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                
authenticate 'cosmic.tar.gz' against 'cosmic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'cosmic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease               
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease             
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                       
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Nov  5 09:49:38 2018) ===
```

As far as I can tell, this is all pretty normal until "Restoring original system state".

For the record, here is the output of "do-release-upgrade -d". Pretty useless (since I obviously *am* trying to upgrade from the latest supported release).

```
# do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

Moreover, upgrading with the "update-manager" GUI also fails without an error message. It goes through the menus and motions until "Preparing to upgrade" and then quits, without saying why, just before "Setting new software channels".

I am pretty comfortable with debugging things. My problem is that there is no indication of what went wrong, so I don't know what to fix. Is there a more detailed log file generated somewhere? Is there a verbose option? Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there a way to manually update to the next version, ignoring the upgrade tools and using just apt or dpkg?

Comment: It may be good sign. Do you really want to feel all the pain with all unneeded upgrades? Stay on LTS and live 5 years without pain... After some time you will be able to install newer HWE on it if you have bleeding egde hardware.

Comment: Yes, I would like to upgrade to 18.10.

Comment: Did you run `apt full-upgrade` first?

Comment: Yes, I ran `apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: The crude way would be to change "bionic" in sources.list to "cosmic" but that may not go smoothly all the way.

Comment: I did the manual upgrade suggested by Jos. It seems to have worked, in a manner (there were a number of inconsistencies that I had to resolve by hand). I suspect it did not solve the underlying problem with do-release-upgrade, so I expect I will have a similar issue when upgrading to 19.04. But it solved my immediate problem for now. Thanks.